# Outlook - Email - HTML - CSS - Right-align content

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to create a report that will be delivered via email. Outlook is a required application in our environment. The content of the report is HTML and it uses table-based layout. Some of the content needs to be right-aligned.  However, Outlook does not appear to be displaying the content as being right-aligned in a table cell.

How do I right-align content in HTML that will be delivered to Outlook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<td align="right">`