# MFMailComposeViewController text alignment with out html - possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create an email with a push of a button in my app. The code works fine but I want the text to be aligned to the right. Is it possibile? (couldn't find any documentation to support this)

Comment: no, it is not possible with plain text

Comment: accordingly to the answer of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434869/outlook-email-html-css-right-align-content) just like this: `<td align="right">Your text</td>`